# I can not install npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vscode-extensions

So I tried installing npm in the folder but it always threw an error. I tried deleting and installing node, `npm chache clean --force` but that did not work.

This is the error message:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\sz_da\OneDrive\Asztali gép\css-master/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\sz_da\OneDrive\Asztali gép\css-master\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sz_da\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-03T19_13_44_560Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Do you have a file at `C:\Users\sz_da\OneDrive\Asztali gép\css-master\package.json`? The error specifically says that this file (that defines what npm packages to install) is missing.

Comment: no I don't have because as usually when i run 'npm install' that made thatjson file

Comment: Run `npm init` to generate a package.json then run `npm install`

Comment: Note that what you did/asked is not "install npm", but "execute `npm install`". Removing ambiguity is very important when asking questions. Besides, try not to put source code in a OneDrive folder (the file path indicates that), as the background OneDrive process(es) often conflicts with other developer tools and lead to various miserable issues (mostly permissions related but can also be others). Just use a normal folder and then configure source code management system like Git.